# How to always display line detail into lineChart - using angular-nvd3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using lineChart -> http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart

Instead of displayed the detail into tooltip, i want the detail always display on the chart:

[image]

How can I handle this case ? Any workaround solution ?
Thank you!